# am using ubuntu 12.10. unable to use PHP_PERL extension. Unable to install the extension as well

Tags: php, perl, ubuntu

I need to run a Perl script because I need a module that Perl has that PHP does not.

This is my code for testing purposes in PHP

```
<?php


echo ("Hello World");


$perl = new Perl();
$perl->require("someperlscript.pl");
```

I got

```
Hello WorldPHP Fatal error:  Class 'Perl' not found in /var/virtual/abc.com/testperl/testperl.php on line 7
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/virtual/abc.com/testperl/testperl.php:0
```

Then I tried to [install to no avail](https://askubuntu.com/q/245996/10591).

What should I do to get Perl running inside a ubuntu 12.10 server edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer works as of 29 Jan 2013.

First of all, inside ubuntu do

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/perl-1.0.1.tgz
```

to download the tgz file from http://pecl.php.net/package/perl

Unzip the tar

```
tar -zxvf perl-1.0.1.tgz
```

Go into the uncompressed folder

```
cd perl-1.0.1
```

Remove the current php_perl.c because for some reason, it did not work with my php5.

Download another php_perl.c from github repo https://github.com/do-aki/php-ext-perl

```
wget https://raw.github.com/do-aki/php-ext-perl/a3d7db22eb7964ea9cb39ea2f866d10df26655d4/php_perl.c
```

Run this line by line

```
export PHP_PREFIX="/usr"
export PERL_PREFIX="/usr"
$PHP_PREFIX/bin/phpize
./configure --with-perl=$PERL_PREFIX --with-php-config=$PHP_PREFIX/bin/php-config
make
```

If you get errors like `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lperl`, then you need to install

```
sudo apt-get install libperl-dev
```

Install the extension (this step can require root privileges)

```
make install
```

Add perl extension into your php.ini (this step can require root privileges)

```
extension=perl.so
```

Restart your php5-fpm

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

You may get issues to do with locale when you run Perl.

Look at the missing locales. Assuming you have missing en_SG and en_SG.UTF-8

Try

```
sudo locale-gen en_SG en_SG.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

and then reboot.

If you still have locale issues,

Try

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Append the missing locale to LC_ALL

```
LC_ALL = "en_SG.UTF-8"
```

Reboot.

**I want to thank `tm064` from #perl and `NullDev` from #ubuntu for helping me with this solution.**

Comment: https://raw.github.com/do-aki/php-ext-perl/a3d7db22eb7964ea9cb39ea2f866d10df26655d4/php_perl.c is now broken. It does not match with the latest header file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a newer version of perl-1.0.1.tgz available from 2013-01-23.
It has more adequate package.xml (Tried under SuSE 12.2 - everything is OK).

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.10. I cannot get it to work. I got make: *** [php_perl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed